# Why my apps are getting auto-updated despite "Don't auto-update apps" checked?

Tags: application-autoupdate, samsung-galaxy-s-9

In Google Play Store, I have set "Auto-update apps" to "Don't auto-update apps". Still, I have apps automatically updated.

Why?

[image: IMG:]

Still, I get notifications.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I don't use those apps but wondering if they have a setting that permits them to override Google Play selection?

Comment: I remember that Samsung devices also have an "Samsung App Store" that can automatically update apps. Therefore updated apps don't necessarily mean that Google Play Store has installed the update.

Comment: I found "Galaxy Apps" in the Samsung folder. There I could also disable autoupdate. Lets see if that will do any good!

Comment: Experienced this myself today. A new setting seems to have been added in Playstore or maybe it was there earlier but updates are affected by this, apparently.

Set *App download preference* to *ask me everytime* that seems to prevent it, though that wasn't the case earlier

Comment: Ok, it seems my phone ignores both settings in google play and in "Galaxy Apps". Facebook and Instagram are still automatically updated.

Comment: https://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/841216-facebook-instagram-app-automatically-update.html

Comment: How does those apps manage to update behind the back of the system?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Now apps have separate auto-update option in Play store. So disable it, uncheck it.

Answer (score 1):

disable Facebook services.
Instagram and Facebook are both auto updated by Facebook_services.
welcome to no longer having control over your own personal data collecting devices.